# JOLT: copy attributes from another array, matching by key value

Tags: json, jolt

Given the following `input` json:

```json
{
  "colleges": [
    {
      "id": 10369272,
      "name": "UNIVERSITY OF SAN DIEGO"
    },
    {
      "id": 10331208,
      "name": "UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA - BERKELEY (EXTENSION)"
    },
    {
      "id": 10331207,
      "name": "SEATTLE PACIFIC UNIVERSITY"
    }
  ],
  "degrees": [
    {
      "id": 6215911,
      "type": "Bachelor of Arts",
      "collegeId": 10331207
    },
    {
      "id": 6235281,
      "type": "Bachelor of Science",
      "collegeId": 10331208
    }
  ]
}
```

and the desired `output` of:

```json
{
  "colleges": [
    {
      "name": "UNIVERSITY OF SAN DIEGO"
    },
    {
      "name": "UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA - BERKELEY (EXTENSION)",
      "degreeType": "Bachelor of Science"
    },
    {
      "name": "SEATTLE PACIFIC UNIVERSITY",
      "degreeType": "Bachelor of Arts"
    }
  ]
}
```

how would a JOLT spec look like to associate correct degrees with correct colleges?

In other words I need to locate a correct `degree` by the college id, extract its `type` and place it under the correct `college`.

Struggling to find a similar example somewhere.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk through the indexes of **colleges** array along with **shift** transformation

by contribution of **`&2[#(1)].@(1,id)`** identifiers
in order to combine the attributes under common

**`collegeId`** ( **`@(1,id)`** and **`@(3,degrees[&].collegeId)`**) values while wrapping all set of the objects

with **`colleges`** array (**`@(1,&2[#(1)])`**) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "colleges": {
        "*": {
          "name": "&2[#1].@(1,id).&",
          "@(2,degrees[&].type)": "&2[#].@(3,degrees[&].collegeId).degreeType"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Barbaros, for your answer. It is almost perfect. However, the spec seems to associate degrees with colleges by position, and not by `collegeId`. Some colleges have no degrees, but this spec associates the first degree with the first college.

Comment: It is perfect now, thank you.

Comment: you're welcome @RomanSvystun , lately I've realised the problem and I was trying to fix it :)